# Desescalar números

Tags: r

Tengo un df

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c(13,234,43),col2=c(32345,34534,74574))
```

Escalo sus valores

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, scale)->df
```

Quiero aplicar una librería y me da error poque dice que los datos no son numéricos (haciendo un str(df) me dice que si lo son)

Lo vuelvo a convertir en numérico:

```
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, as.numeric)->df
```

Ahora si me deja operar.

Hago los operaciones y al terminar quiero desescalar, es decir, volver a los valores de antes. Pero no veo que scale tenga esa función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empiezo por el error que te da porque el output de `scale` "no es numérico".

La función `scale()` **no** regresa un vector numérico simple, en realidad regresa un objeto de las clases `matrix` y `array`. Como estás usando `mutate_if()` hace eso para cada columna y te regresa un data.frame que en cada columna tiene ese combo de `matrix` `array`. Un df al fin y al cabo es un lista, así que una columna puede ser de cualquier clase, siempre que el largo siempre sea el mismo. Lo más común es que sea una lista de vectores, pero nada impide que sea una lista de listas, matrices, arrays, etc.

```
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, scale) %>% sapply(class)
     col1     col2    
[1,] "matrix" "matrix"
[2,] "array"  "array"
```

Por lo tanto si la función que vas a usar después espera un vector numérico va a dar error. Eso es lo que estás resolviendo con el as.numeric, le quitas atributos al objeto más complejo y lo dejas como un vector numérico simple y funciona.

¿Qué atributos le quitas? Si lo exploras con `str()` vas encontrar algo interesante:

```
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, scale) %>% str()

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  $ col1: num [1:3, 1] -0.698 1.146 -0.448
..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 96.7
..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 120
$ col2: num [1:3, 1] -0.623 -0.531 1.153
..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 47151
..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 23774
```

Por un lado cada columna tiene una matriz de 3*1. Tiene implícitas más de una dimensión (por eso dice [1:3, 1]), aunque solo use una. Es una matriz, pero por el método `print()` se ve como si fuera un vector numérico sin más. No lo es.

Lo más interesante son los atributos que están en `attr`. Ahí tienes:

1. el valor central que se usó para el escalado de cada columna.
2. la escala que se usó para cada columna.

Con esos dos números se puede desescalar el valor: multiplicas `x` por la escala y le sumas el valor central.

Va una prueba simple:

```
x1 = 13
x1 escalado = -0.6979415
La escala de x = 119.8763
El centro de x = 96.66667

(-0.6979415 * 119.8763) + 96.66667 = 13.00003
```

No da exactamente 13, pero esto es cuestiones de redondeo de los métodos print que usé para obtener los números. Si en lugar de hacerlo "a mano" lo haces usando los objetos en R vas a tener resultados más precisos (que no exactos porque coma flotante).

¿Cómo podrías resolver el problema en un caso práctico? Va una posible solución, que se me antoja complicada. Seguramente hay una forma más simple de hacerlo, pero esta es la que se me ocurre:

```
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, scale) -> df_escalado
```

Como más adelante voy a perder los atributos los guardo.

```
df_escalado %>% sapply(attr, "scaled:center") -> centros
df_escalado %>% sapply(attr, "scaled:scale") -> escalas
```

Lo paso a numérico. Luego de este paso podrías usar otra función y luego trabajar sobre ese output. Es estrictamente necesario que el orden de las columnas sea igual al del inicio. Tienen que quedar  alineadas las listas de centros/escalas y datos escaladas.

```
df_escalado %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric) -> df_escalado_numerico
```

En este caso uso exactamente el mismo input (los valores escalados) para validar que el código logra regresar a los valores originales, previos al escalado:

```
df_escalado_numerico %>% 
map2(.x = ., .y = escalas, ~.x * .y) %>% 
  map2_df(.x = ., .y = centros, ~.x + .y)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    13 32345
2   234 34534
3    43 74574
```

Hago las operaciones matemáticas en dos pasos: primero la multiplicación después la suma. Lo hago manejando listas, que es con lo que estoy más familiarizado. No es elegante, pero funciona.

> PD: la función `map2` te permite hacer operaciones sobre dos listas, en este caso sobre los valores escalados (cada columna de ese data.frame) y sobre las listas de escalas y centros. Son vectores coercionados a lista. Como son dos listas de la misma cantidad de elementos (2) entonce `map2` los empareja y aplica el "escalar" correcto a cada vector.

> Con este enfoque hay muchos caracteres reservados:

> `.` Es el pronombre de los datos que vienen del lado izquierdo.

> `~` Define una función anónima.

> `.x` Es el nombre, dentro del entorno, de los elementos de de una lista. Es el primer argumento y en la función anónima se evalúa con ese nombre.

> `.y` Es el nombre, dentro del entorno, de los elementos de una segunda lista. En `~` se evalúa con ese nombre.

Comment: y si tuviera una col no numérica, ¿como podría modificar la última parte?                                                                                           df<-data.frame(col1=c(13,234,43),col2=c(32345,34534,74574),col3=c(32345,34534,74574),col4=c("a","e","e"))

Comment: Sería bastante más complicado porque no existe un `map2_if`. Es razonable, `map2` depende completamente de que estén alineadas las listas y si usas un condicional (el `if`) eso sería mucho más difícil. Si se te presentan problemas en el orden o `nrow` lo más simple es procesar las numéricas y después `bind_cols()` para reunirlas con las no numéricas. No digo que sea imposible, solo que es más complicado.